# (solved by updating) Measure similarity of sentences to target document's sentences (error msg)

Tags: r, quanteda, sentence-similarity

I am using the R [quanteda package](https://quanteda.io/index.html) (version 1.4.3, windows system) to find almost verbatim text-reuse in several documents. In the end, I want to compare the relative influence of the source documents, plus I want to be able to display instances of near verbatim matches. So far, what I have been doing is this:

- build a corpus from text files
- re-shape it into sentences to be compared
- tokenize it into words
- build a document-feature-matrix from word ngrams

```
library(magrittr)
library(readtext)
library(quanteda)

corpus    <-  readtext("data/*.txt",
                       docvarsfrom = "filenames",
                       dvsep = "_-_",
                       docvarnames = c("country"),
                       encoding = "UTF-8"
                      ) %>%
              corpus()

sentences <-  corpus_reshape(corpus,
                             to = "sentences",
                             use_docvars = TRUE
                            )

mytokens  <-  tokens(sentences,
                     what = "word",
                     include_docvars = TRUE
                    ) %>%
              tokens_ngrams(n = 3:5)

mydfm     <-  dfm(mytokens, tolower = TRUE)
```

Inspecting the results, they seem fine so far.

However, when I try to calculate the similarity of "documents" (i.e. sentences) to "documents" from my target text, I get an error:

```
simil <- textstat_simil(mydfm,
                        dfm_subset(mydfm, country == "USA"),
                        margin = "documents",
                        method = "simple matching"
                       )
Error in selection[is.na(i)] : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting
```

- How can I avoid this error?
- Am I taking a good approach in the first place?

PS. Am I right that it's "include_docvars" in tokens() but "use_docvars" in corpus_reshape()? I seem to have this from the online reference docs.

Comment: Try updating the quanteda package.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have just tried it at home where I have a linux system with quanteda 1.5.1 and lo and behold, everything is working as expected. I cannot try earlier than next week on my office/windows system, but it seems this was indeed the cause. (I think I have installed the package only recently but will make sure - and report back.)

Comment: Okay, I finally managed to update the quanteda package on the windows system also, and it's working now. Sorry for the noise and thanks for the help!